# My VBA is treating the letter D as a number, what is going on?

Tags: excel, vba, string, numbers

I typed `?IsNumeric(1974D01)` into my immediate window and I got this response
`?isNumeric(1974D01) True` What is going on? Why is the `IsNumeric()` function not working properly? I have tried multiple letter and number combos and all that I have found is that if I have a number and then followed by a singular "D" followed by other numbers it creates an issue. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Try `E` too :-) The linked thread is for VB6, but I believe also applicable here.

Comment: do `? Cdbl(1974D01)` it returns `19740`.  Apperently `D##` is akin to `* 10^##`